Why is onLongPress() not functioning properly?
I am making an app where I have a lot of containers, which are all wrapped in an InkWell(). So far, they are quite simple; when you tap a container it takes you to a new screen. I now want to make the container change color when long pressed. I tested this on a different project, and it worked perfectly. However, when I implement it in my actual code, it does't work. The onTap() still works, however, the onLongPress() doesn't execute. The color change never happens when the container is long pressed. Any tips on how to fix this? Thanks in advance.
Code:
class ToolsScreen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  ToolsScreen2({super.key});

  @override
  State<ToolsScreen2> createState() => ToolsScreen2State();
}

class ToolsScreen2State extends State<ToolsScreen2> {
  late Color colorContainer = Colors.white24;
  void initState() {
    colorContainer = Color(
      GetStorage().read<int>('colorContainer') ?? Colors.white24.value,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Choose A CLL Case:'),
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent, 
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          InkWell(
            onLongPress: () {
              setState(() {
                colorContainer = colorContainer == Colors.white24
                    ? Colors.green.shade600
                    : Colors.white24;
                GetStorage().write('colorContainer', colorContainer.value);
              });
            },  // This is the LongPress that doesn't work.
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const Sune_CLL(),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Container(
              width: 500,
              color: Colors.white24,
              height: 125,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    'images/SuneOrtega BR.png',
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 70.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Sune Cases',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),


I have encountered this issue before. You simply forgot to change the color of the Container() to colorContainer. You need to use the colorContainer you made as the color, not a pre-determined color such as white24.
So, change this:
child: Container(
  width: 500,
  color: Colors.white24. <— Change this.
  height: 125, 

To this:
child: Container(
  width: 500,
  color: colorContainer,<— use colorContainer
  height: 125,

Hope this helped!

Can't believe I missed this. But thank you! Cheers.
